# Delete records from child table in groovy

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have domain classes as following:

```
class A {

    static hasMany = [b: B]

}

class B {

    static hasMany = [c: C]

}

class C {

    static belongsTo = B

}
```

Here I want to delete records from Table B and C. How to do this ?

In my method, what i actually want to do is, check if A has records of B, if yes then delete it. I tried by doing native queries but it threw foreign key exception. Please give solution if anybody knows it. Thank you.

```
def myMethod(a){
    if (a.b) {
        // delete b
    }   
}
```

Comment: put `static belongsTo = A' into class B

Comment: I recommend you read the 3 part GORM gotchas: http://spring.io/blog/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/, it will answer most of your current and future questions on these type of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [configure the cascading behavior of an association](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/cascade.html)